# Subspace Hyperplan

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

We have a vector space $V$ with a finite dimension on $\lambda$. We consider the hyperplane $H$ with $\dim H=\dim V-1$. We consider an arbitrary subspace $U$ of $V$.

If $U \not\subseteq H$, we can write $V=U+H$ and $\dim(U \cap H) =\dim U-1$.

Here are my questions:

1. I do not understand where does $V=U+H$ come from.
2. I have to show the characteristics with $U \subset H$.

Here's my reasoning: if $U$ is contained in $H$:

$$U+H=H \implies \dim(U+H)=\dim H$$

I can rewrite the formula to get $$\dim(U+H)=\dim U+\dim H-\dim(U \cap H) \\ \iff \dim(U \cap H)=\dim U+\dim H-\dim(U+H)=\dim U+\dim H-\dim H=\dim U$$

Can we find a relation between $\dim U$ and $\dim V$?

3. Given $d:=\dim U \lt \dim V =: n$ I have to show that there exist hyperplanes $H_1,
       ... , H_{n-d}$  such that

$$U=\bigcap_{k=1} ^{n-d} H_k$$

For this one i wanted to complete  the basis of $U$ until $V$, but i dont know how to write this in a correct way.

Comment: **How to format your questions 101:** to get $V_i$, type `$V_i$`. To get $\dim(U)$, type `$\dim(U)$`. To get $U \cup V \cap W$, type `$U \cup V \cap W$`. To get $a+b-c^2=\frac{1-2}{b}$, type `$a+b-c^2=\frac {1-2}{b}$`. To get $a \le b \iff b \gt a \text{ or } b = a$, type `$a \le b \iff b \gt a \text{ or } b = a$`. Finally, to get something on it's own line, like $$U + H = H \implies \dim(U+H) = \dim(H)$$ type double `$`'s, like `$$U + H = H \implies \dim(U+H) = \dim(H)$$`. For more info, see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i did an edit.

Comment: Yes you are right i did a false expression i will correct it

Comment: For $(1)$, if $U \not\subseteq H$, then $U+H$ (which is always a subspace) must be a *larger* subspace than $U$ or $H$.  But because $H$ is a hyperplane -- that is, a subspace of dimension $\lambda -1$ -- the only subspace larger than $H$ is $V$.  Thus $U+H=V$.  For $(2)$ I don't know what you mean by the characteristics with $U$.  But to answer your last sentence in that section, if $U+H=H$, and $H$ is a proper subspace of $V$, then all we can say is $\dim(U) \lt \dim(H) \lt \dim(V)$.  I don't know how to prove $(3)$ off the top of my head.  If I figure it out later I'll write up an answer.

Comment: I tried to fix your formatting and wording a little.  Make sure it's still correct.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation at the point 1. The first point was given in order to help us for the second one. In which i have to show what is the dimension of $dim(U+H)$ with  $U⊂H$.